# Getting top results from Redis hash

Tags: redis

I am trying to write a query in Redis to get the first 2 field values of my hash key..

Basically, when I do `HVALS hashname`, I want to get the values of the first 2 fields added (the oldest 2). This is somewhat like getting the TOP 2 tuples in a SQL database.

Is this possible in redis?

Comment: Since it's a hash, the elements are of no order, i.e. there's no oldest or top. You might want to try the `LIST` or `SORTED SET` structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The order of fields and values in a Redis Hash is for all intents and purposes random (despite the empirical evidence obtained on from experimenting on smallish Hashes). For ordering elements, refer to Redis' Sorted Sets.

Update: to answer the question in the comment, IIUC it looks like you can solve it easily with just Strings. Because of Redis' nature, at any given moment there is either one user waiting for a specific match, or zero. You can `SET matchmaking:blue username1:token` if the key doesn't exist (i.e. zero users waiting for the match) and `GET` and `DEL` it if it exists. Be sure to use `SET`'s "NX" subcommand, `MULTI/EXEC` and/or Lua to ensure the atomicity of these two logical operations.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How would you go around organizing this problem?

I am building a matchmaking algorithm where I want to match people that input a certain string in my application. For instance, if I input "blue", I would do `HSET matchmaking:blue username1 pushNotificationToken`. Then, another user that inputs "blue" would also get placed in that hash in the same fashion. 

Every new input in a particular hash also checks if the length of it is 2 or more. If it is, it should take the first 2 people that inputted "blue" and match them together, removing them from the hash.

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it is not possible to assume that there can only be 1 or 0 people waiting. Also, I can not make the operations atomic because this will be an API for a mobile app where hundreds of users can be requesting the same input at the same time. Assume 10 users inputted "blue" in almost the same time, with negligent differences in time. I still need to pair them up 2 by 2.

Comment: Redis is single threaded, so even if 100 users all send at the same time, the requests will still be dealt with one but one. Since you're pairing users, either there's no one to pair the incoming request with (zero) or there is (one). I still think I'm right, but feel free to disregard and disagree.

Comment: So here's an idea for a new feature: an `OrderedHash`, akin to python `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

From what I have experimented with, `HVALS` returns values for keys in the order you're looking for i.e. oldest key first. Now its up to you to only pick the first two values using the client program e.g. `HSET myhmap name "abhi"` , `HSET myhmap email "test@test"` , `HSET myhmap planet "earth"`, `HSET myhmap galaxy "andromeda"`. `HVALS myhmap` will return `"abhi","test@test"`, `"earth"` , `"andromeda"`

Comment: Despite the experiments, you can not rely on this. Once the Hash's encoding is changed from ziplist (used for smaller values), this no longer holds.

Comment: As  a workaround (this might sound overkill) - you can store `hash` fields in a list (initially using `RPUSH`) and in order to fetch values you can invoke `HMGET` on specific keys which you can get from the list using `LINDEX` 0 and 1 (first two elements)